# ¿Porque se me duplica los elementos? javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, date

estoy creando un CRUD con fetch, el problema lo tengo cuando quiero agregar un nuevo usuario, ya que en lugar de agregarse el nuevo usuario  se me duplica los usuario anteriores y luego si se agrega el que acabo de crear

Este es el formulario cunado carga la pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto pasa cuando agrego un nuevo ususario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aclaro que lo datos duplicados no se guardan en la base de datos, ya que cuando recargo la pagina manualmente aparecen los datos como deben de ser(un dato por usuario) pero la idea no es recargar la pagina sino que dinamicamente aparezca el nuevo usuario(ajax)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Practica01</title>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4" >
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-dark" style="color: #e1dfdf;">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center"><strong>Registar Personas</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="formulario">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="tipo_identificacion" id="tipo_identificacion" class="form-control" required=required>
                <option value="">Seleccione Identificacion</option>
                <option value="Tarjeta Identidad">Tarjeta Identidad</option>
                <option value="Cedula Ciudadania">Cedula Ciudadania</option>
                <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Id" required=required> 
              <input type="number" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" class="form-control" placeholder="Identififcacion" required=required> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres" required=required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" required=required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="form-control" required=required>
                <option value="">Seleccione Sexo</option>
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a name="btn-guardar" id="btn-guardar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#" role="button">Guardar</a>
              <a name="btn-actualizar" id="btn-actualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="#" role="button">Actualizar</a>
              <a name="btn-cancelar" id="btn-cancelar" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" href="#" role="button">Cancelar</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="col-9 table-responsive-sm"> 
        <table class="table text-center ">
        <h5 class="text-center"><strong>Lista de Personas</strong></h5>
          <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
              <th>Tipo Identificaion</th>
              <th>N° Identificaion</th>
              <th >Nombre</th>
              <th>Apellidos</th>
              <th>Sexo</th>
              <th colspan="2" >Acciones</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="listar-personas">

          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="librerias/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="librerias/fontawesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**CODIGO JAVASCRIPT**

```
    /* ------------------------------- LISTAR PERSONAS --------------------------------- */
    addEventListener('load', () => {
        listarPersonas();
    })


    function listarPersonas() {
        fetch('listar-personas.php')
        .then(response => response.ok ? Promise.resolve(response) : Promise.reject(response))
            .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    const listaPersonas = document.getElementById("listar-personas");
                    const fragmento = document.createDocumentFragment();
                    for (const personas of response) {

                    //Crear Elementos
                    const filaTabla = document.createElement("tr");
                    const tipoIdentificacion = document.createElement("td");
                    const numeroIdentificacion = document.createElement("td");
                    const nombre = document.createElement("td");
                    const apellido = document.createElement("td");
                    const sexo = document.createElement("td")
                    const tdEliminar = document.createElement("td");
                    const tdactualizar = document.createElement("td");
                    const botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
                    const botonactualizar = document.createElement("button");

                    //Asginar Valor
                    tipoIdentificacion.textContent = personas.tipo_identificacion;
                    numeroIdentificacion.textContent = personas.identificacion;
                    nombre.textContent = personas.nombre;
                    apellido.textContent = personas.apellido;
                    sexo.textContent = personas.sexo;

                    botonEliminar.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>`;
                    botonactualizar.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>`;

                    //Asginar Atributos
                    filaTabla.setAttribute("id", personas.id_persona);
                    botonEliminar.setAttribute("id", "btn-eliminar");

                    //Asginar Clases
                    botonEliminar.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger");
                    botonactualizar.classList.add("btn", "btn-success");


                    //Agregar Elementos Al Fragmento
                    fragmento.appendChild(filaTabla).appendChild(tipoIdentificacion).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', numeroIdentificacion).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', nombre).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', apellido).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', sexo).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', tdEliminar).appendChild(botonEliminar).parentElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', tdactualizar).appendChild(botonactualizar);

                }              
                    listaPersonas.appendChild(fragmento)                
            }
        )
        .catch(reject => console.log(reject))
}

/* ------------------------------- REGISTRAR PERSONAS --------------------------------- */

const btnGuardar = document.getElementById('btn-guardar');
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

btnGuardar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let datos = new FormData(formulario);

    fetch('guardar-personas.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            listarPersonas();
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que no limpias el elemento `#listar-personas` cada que invocas la función `listarPersonas()`.

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
/* ------------------------------- LISTAR PERSONAS --------------------------------- */
addEventListener('load', () => {
  listarPersonas();
})

function listarPersonas() {
  const listaPersonas = document.getElementById("listar-personas");
  fetch('listar-personas.php')
    .then(response => response.ok ? Promise.resolve(response) : Promise.reject(response))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      listaPersonas.innerHTML = ''; // con esto evitaremos que se dupliquen
      // ojo: listaPersonas.innerHTML = ''; debe ir por encima de todo, para que así siempre se renueve el contenido
      const fragmento = document.createDocumentFragment();
      for (const personas of response) {

        //Crear Elementos
        const filaTabla = document.createElement("tr");
        const tipoIdentificacion = document.createElement("td");
        const numeroIdentificacion = document.createElement("td");
        const nombre = document.createElement("td");
        const apellido = document.createElement("td");
        const sexo = document.createElement("td")
        const tdEliminar = document.createElement("td");
        const tdactualizar = document.createElement("td");
        const botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
        const botonactualizar = document.createElement("button");

        //Asginar Valor
        tipoIdentificacion.textContent = personas.tipo_identificacion;
        numeroIdentificacion.textContent = personas.identificacion;
        nombre.textContent = personas.nombre;
        apellido.textContent = personas.apellido;
        sexo.textContent = personas.sexo;

        botonEliminar.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>`;
        botonactualizar.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>`;

        //Asginar Atributos
        filaTabla.setAttribute("id", personas.id_persona);
        botonEliminar.setAttribute("id", "btn-eliminar");

        //Asginar Clases
        botonEliminar.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger");
        botonactualizar.classList.add("btn", "btn-success");
        console.log(fragmento);

        //Agregar Elementos Al Fracmento
        fragmento.appendChild(filaTabla).appendChild(tipoIdentificacion).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', numeroIdentificacion).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', nombre).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', apellido).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', sexo).insertAdjacentElement('afterend', tdEliminar).appendChild(botonEliminar).parentElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', tdactualizar).appendChild(botonactualizar);
        console.log(fragmento);
      }
      listaPersonas.appendChild(fragmento)
    })
    .catch(reject => console.log(reject))
}

/* ------------------------------- REGISTRAR PERSONAS --------------------------------- */

const btnGuardar = document.getElementById('btn-guardar');
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

btnGuardar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let datos = new FormData(formulario);

  fetch('guardar-personas.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: datos
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      listarPersonas();
    })
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo probé y funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

el problema está en que no estás reiniciando las filas de la tabla cuando obtienes una nueva lista de personas.
Cada vez que guardas, vuelves a consultar la tabla y por consecuencia te trae toda la lista. La solución sería que hagas un reset de las filas de la siguiente forma:

```
listarPersonas.innerHTML = '';
```

Luego continúas con el código de llenar el fagmento.